# Getting sub-graph result in ArangoDb

Tags: arangodb, subgraph

I'm using ArangoDB of the respective release series: 3.1

Mode: Single-Server

On this operating system: Windows, version: 10

Kindly ask to know how to get a sub-graph result for a query in ArangoDb?

For example:
If I have students nodes linked to a university node by (studyAt) edge and I need to see only the students that have ages > 21, so I need to see a sub-graph that contain only these students linked to the university node.

Comment: Hi, did you make any attempt? It would be great if you can provide an example, check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this use case you can use an AQL graph traversal starting at your university node with depth 1. Applying the filter age > 21 on the first level vertices will make sure that only students with an age value > 21 are returned.

The following AQL query is a draft, which has to be adjusted using your variable names.

```
FOR v, e, p IN 1..1 ANY 'universityCollection/universityNode' GRAPH 'yourGraph'
  FILTER p.vertices[1].age > 21
  RETURN v
```

After executing this query in the web interface the result is shown as JSON and graph and the sub-graph result can be downloaded as a JSON file.

Further information on how to use graph traversals can be found in the [AQL documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html).

Comment: Hi Maximilian Kernbach, thank you for your reply it was so helpful!
I want to ask you another question please: The result is shown as JSON and Table only so how can I see it as a Graph? (I mean as nodes and edges like on graph section in the web interface)

Comment: Just replace "RETURN v" with "RETURN p", which will return the path as a result. This will allow you to choose Graph instead of Table and open the result in the Graph Viewer as well.